# Laravel ajax form submit validation message not working

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2  and i'm using Laravel's Form Post Validation method. It is validating as expected. But if validation fails it should return the error message as JSON since i'm sending an ajax request. But it is returning the previous page as html.
My request is looks like :
[image]

as per Laravel Docs in https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#working-with-error-messages it shoud return a json. Is there anything i missed ?

Comment: Check your headers, try `"Accept": "application/json"` or  `dataType : 'json'`

Comment: Its Works with your suggestion. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

When validation fails, the response is 422 HTTP status code. In ajax you need get it in `error:` section.

It'll be like following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        // Process if there is not error
    },
    error: function(data){
        // Error in json object. Process with errors.
    }
});
```

Comment: i have handled the error as you said . but it is returning 200 response. that is the reason i'm posting this question. it should return 422

Comment: Hi its working as i added setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, text/javascript')